# Cordova 3.3.0 Error NSInternalInconsistencyException reason: ERROR: Config.xml does not exist

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using Cordova 3.3.0 on a mac with xcode 5 and as soon as i launch the app, right after the native splash screen, it crashes with the above error. I noticed this has happened after I played around trying to change the splash screen plugin image. It happened after renaming of default-portrait.png and default-568h@2x.png

The exception also logs that i need to run cordova-ios/bin/cordova_plist_to_config_xml. Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException. I do not know what needs to be done here.

I do not see what this has to do with the config.xml or why it has reacted now since I have been using this plugin for a week now with no issues.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I started a fresh copy of the project I think that solved the issue. make sure you update cordova.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing the same